# How in the Traffic Flow Equation (quasilinear first order pde) come back to original variables if the solution is written in parametric variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following quasilinear PDE (The Traffic Flow model):
$$u_t + (1+u)u_x = 0, u(x,0) = f(x)$$

[image]

My solution is the following:
$$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1$$
$$\frac{dx}{ds} = 1 + u$$
$$\frac{du}{ds} = 0$$
with IC : $s = 0$, $t(0) = 0$, $x(0) = \xi$

From the first eq. with imposed IC we get: $$t = s$$
From the third eq. with imposed IC we get $$u = f(\xi)$$
From the second eq. with imposed IC we get $$x = (1+f(\xi))t + \xi$$

Thus the solution is of the form:
$$x(t,s) = (1+f(\xi))t + \xi, u(:,\xi) = f(\xi)$$

The question is how to write the solution $u(x,t)$

Comment: Since $u$ is written in terms of $t$ and $\xi$, and you want it in terms of $t$ and $x$, you should try to invert the map $(t,\xi) \mapsto x(t,\xi)$ which you know is $(1+f(\xi))t+\xi$.

Comment: \begin{align} u &= f(\xi) \\ \xi &= x - (1 + f(\xi))t \\ &= x - (1 + u)t \\ \implies u &= f(x - (1 + u)t) \end{align}

Comment: Note that for the nonlinear case, you usually cannot do better than an implicit representation of the solution except for special initial conditions.

Comment: Graphing $x(t,\xi)$ on Desmos, it looks to be invertible for $-1<t<1$, but the explicit formula might be slightly unwieldy (though not terribly complex either).